# How to configure MX for different host

Tags: mx-record

Situation is this: I have OldServer and NewServer with olddomain.com and newdomain.com

Both servers run postfix and dovecot. For the purpose of moving between OldServer and NewServer I want to set up an MX record for

**mail2.newdomain.com -> 10 olddomain.com**

So basically I want to reach OldServer's email with newdomain.com. But this doesn't work. Mail clients don't give an error message, they just can't reach the host (OldServer).

DIG shows mail2.newdomain.com outputs the record above correctly.

The reason is that I can first configure existing mail clients to use mail2.newdomain.com and then transfer olddomain.com so there's no interruption. Also for NewServer I want to setup separate MX records for different mail clients, but thats not part of this question, just an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a *Mail Exchange* `MX` record for servers that are supposed to handle mail for the domain. This means you don't set `mail2.example.com MX 10 example.net`, because that isn't a forward from `mail2.example.com` to `example.net`, but it says that mail sent to **address `user@mail2.example.com`** is handled by the **server at `example.net`** (the IP address defined in the `A` record for it).

If you wan't server `mail.example.net` handle mail for both old `example.com` and new `example.net` and the IP address of your new mail server is `198.51.100.100` (`TEST-NET-2` example address), the correct DNS records would be:

```
example.com.         IN MX     0 mail.example.net.

example.net.         IN MX     0 mail.example.net.
mail.example.net.    IN A      198.51.100.100
```

If you need your IMAP and submission clients (as well as some webmail) to be accessible with your old addresses, you can add `A` or `CNAME` records. Let's assume we have set the records on the first example i.e. `mail.example.net A 198.51.100.100`. To achieve this we might add this kind of records:

```
imap.example.com.    IN CNAME  mail.example.net.
mail.example.com.    IN CNAME  mail.example.net.
webmail.example.com. IN CNAME  mail.example.net.
```

Comment: EDIT: I need to setup all of your example containing example.com on the old server and all containing example.net on the new server, right?

Comment: Depends on what you want on the new server: is it going to replace the old one. Hopefully you now have some idea what's the purpose of the `MX` record.